# Mongodb $geoNear operator not working correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm building nodejs api using mongodb as database for Android app.
When an Android user sends his GPS position to back end, the api sorts all data by the distance from the user and replies back.

For this, I'm using $geoNear stage in aggregation framework. I followed the instructions, but I can't get data, only "undefined".

Here is JSON data format from db.

```
{
   userId: "",
   description: "",
   location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [ latitude, longitude ]
   },
   image: ""
}
```

And here is my geoNear code.

```
db.posts.createIndex({location:"2dsphere"});
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ parseFloat(geoInfo.latitude) , parseFloat(geoInfo.longitude) ] },
            distanceField: "distance",
            spherical: true
        }
    },
    { $sort: { distance: 1 } },
    { $limit: 20 }
], function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    }
    callback(null, docs);
});
```

I can see only undefined result.
Now I'm stuck in this issue for a few days.
Any helps are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code.

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
var collection = db.collection("posts");

console.log(collection.listIndexes);

// Wait for a second before finishing up, to ensure we have written the item to disk
setTimeout(function() {
    collection.aggregate([ {
        $geoNear : {
            near : {
                type : "Point",
                coordinates : [ parseFloat(-73.97), parseFloat(40.77) ]
            },
            distanceField : "distance",
            spherical : true
        }
    }, {
        $sort : {
            distance : 1
        }
    }, {
        $limit : 20
    } ], function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("completed...........");
        console.log("doc ====>" + JSON.stringify(docs));
    });
}, 1000);
});
```

**Inserts and Create Index commands:-**

```
db.posts.insert(
{
  userId : "user1",
  description : "desc 1",
  loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },
  name: "Central Park",
  category : "Parks",
  image : "image 1"
}
)

db.posts.insert(
{
  userId : "user2",
  description : "desc 2",
  loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.88, 40.78 ] },
  name: "La Guardia Airport",
  category : "Airport",
  image : "image 2"
}
)

db.posts.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )
```

Comment: Hi Notionquest, thank you for the kind answer. Your code seems working on sample data, but when I bring it on my database, it's also not working.

Comment: Here is an error.
`"errmsg": "exception: geoNear command failed: { errmsg: \"exception: 'near' field must be point\", code: 17304, ok: 0.0 }",`

Comment: Please provide an exact sample copy of your document ( 1 or 2 documents). Otherwise, it would be difficult to debug your issue.

Comment: I found the solution. The reason is that I wrote coordinates by [lat, lng]. Actually it should be written by [lng, lat]. Thank you for the help